# Which society in Japan is responsible for the age requirement system for manga/comics?

Tags: law

I found that an age requirement system exists for movies and anime made by a society, [Eirin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eirin), but I didn't find an equivalent for manga and comics in Japan. I would be curious to be able to compare age rating of the same manga in France and in Japan.

Comment: Do comics in France have an age rating? I don't believe there are any formal age ratings for comics in the US, for example.

Comment: For the so-called (in English) Hentai genre, it is self-rated by the publishers' side ([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%90%E4%BA%BA%E5%90%91%E3%81%91%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB#%E5%87%BA%E7%89%88%E3%83%BB%E6%B5%81%E9%80%9A%E6%A5%AD%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AE%E8%87%AA%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%8F%E5%88%B6))

Comment: Related [When and why has the censorship of obscenity for hentai changed?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/67632)

Comment: @F1Krazy In France we don't have an official age rating for books and comics. The age indicated on comics come from the publishers. Maybe it is the same in Japan. I asked anyway because I wasn't sure that my failure to find the information was not caused by my use of bad keywords on Google. Finding the right kyword is sometime tricky.