# Why is there no nudity in Darling in the Franxx?

Tags: darling-in-the-franxx

Darling in the Franxx has a lot of sexual undertones in it and it's not exactly subtle about it. Why doesn't it have any nudity then? I'm not talking about full blown hentai, I'm talking about some bare breasts here and there. It's not exactly for small children anyway, so... what gives? Even Ranma 1/2, if I remember correctly, had bare breasts in its original airing. I know it was a very different time, but still...

Judging from the manga, the creators don't have any qualms about showing female nipples, so why did they hold back on the anime? ... Did they just reserve it for the manga as an additional selling point or what? I heard the manga is successful, but I doubt it's just because of that, but I could be wrong...

Comment: i get the feeling it might have been because of what time they aired it in Japan though i don't know when it was. generally in other countries a show's content dictates at what time during the day/night it's aired. ie. you won't see *Deadpool* aired between *Seasme Street* and *Play School* just like how video game review programs reviewing Mature games don't get aired in the morning with similar (is not the same) programs that review more all ages games

Comment: Related? [What are the anime censorship laws in Japan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4940/2516) and their linked/related links...

Comment: @AkiTanaka I don't think that's related, since it's less about if it's legal and more about why they didn't do it. Unless the law changed since Ranma 1/2 aired (or I remembered the scenes wrong and there actually wasn't any nudity), I don't see why showing female nipples on TV would suddenly be illegal.

Comment: The law has absolutely changed since Ranma 1/2. Look up the "Tokyo Youth Ordinance Bill Amendment" for just one example. Also, this isn't so much about law; a channel's owners and staff can totally decide not to show something regardless of the law.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it's because Darling in the Franxx is mainly about romance and action. They were mainly talking about the love between Hiro and Zero Two, so I don't think it's necessary for them to show nudity. Also, even if Darling in the Franxx is not for small children, it shouldn't show nudity, because the genre is not ecchi.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not a hentai, so I don't think it's required to show any nudity. It does count as an ecchi, but it's only ecchi if it doesn't show any nudity (from what I know). if the show added nudity, it would probably raise the age rating to 18+, and then Studio Trigger and Cloverworks would most likely lose "views". It might not appeal to some adults, and besides; the show itself is more suitable for 13-year-olds. (Hence the current age rating.)
I hope this helps :)